"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" with big bidimensional arrays
I made a small program for splitting big files into smaller ones with Java.
The code is the following:
import java.io.*;
public class Main {

    final static int DIM = 6;
    final static int GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    public static void write(char[][] buffer, long currentFile) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out" + currentFile + ".json"))) {
            long wrote = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
                int firstNull = GB;
                for(int j = GB - 1; j > 0; j--){
                    if(buffer[i][j] == '\0'){
                        firstNull = j;
                    }
                }
                bw.write(buffer[i], 0, firstNull);
                wrote += firstNull;
            }
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Wrote " + wrote + " bytes to <out" + currentFile + ".json>");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        File file = new File("./twd.json");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            int bufPos = 0;
            int mapIdx = 0;
            char[][] buffer = new char[DIM][GB];
            long currentFile = 0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            System.out.println("Config correct => Started");
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(bufPos + line.length() >= GB){
                    if(mapIdx == DIM - 1){
                        write(buffer, currentFile);
                        buffer = null; // Otherwise it will trigger OutOfMemoryError
                        buffer = new char[DIM][GB];
                        bufPos = 0;
                        double progress = GB * (currentFile + 1.0) /  (file.length() / (double) DIM) * 100;
                        System.out.println("Status: " +  progress + "%");
                        currentFile++;
                        mapIdx = 0;
                    }else{
                        mapIdx++;
                        bufPos = 0;
                        System.out.println("Map idx to " + mapIdx);
                    }
                }
                int i;
                for(i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
                    buffer[mapIdx][bufPos] = line.charAt(i);
                    bufPos++;
                }
                buffer[mapIdx][bufPos] = '\n';
                bufPos++;
            }
            write(buffer, currentFile);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            br.close();

            System.out.println("Diff: " + (end - start) / 1000 + "s");
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
        }
    }
}

The problem that I encounter is the following, the memory usage of the program should be DIM * GB * 2 (a char is 2 bytes) GB. With DIM = 5 everything works fine. If I try to increment it, it throws that error.
I've tried to pass an additional -Xmx param for incrementing the max heap size. But without any luck. (My system has 48GB of RAM, but even trying to specify -Xmx(n)g where n is a insane high number (< 40) does not work.)
I noticed that without any additional parameters and with DIM = 5, the task manager shows me that the program reaches the usage of 12GB of RAM.
Am I missing something?

"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" is thrown when I try to initialize the char[][] and DIM is greater or equals to 6.

I know the code can be more efficient and definitely simpler, but I was wondering what was causing the program to crash and why (I can't figure it out) rather than just making it work :)

Saying a char is 2 bytes is a little oversimplified. The array itself has some very minor overhead, but passing char[] to a Writer (namely Buffered > File > OutputStreamWriter > StreamEncoder) will ultimately wrap each char[] in CharBuffer, and encode the result, so there's definitely more being used. With reading as well, no wonder your usage is up. What's interesting is that DIM=6 failed you, more so than any other higher number. A much more efficient solution may be writing the file as you read it, instead of reading whole chunks like this.

For whatever reasons, I dont understand that code.

Why do you even need this huge buffer to begin with? All your code seems to do is split the file into chunks of at most 6 GB, while ensuring that the split happens at a line break. This means that you know whether you can write a line as soon as you encounter the end of that line. If you were to write the line at that time, you would only need to hold a single line in memory, which would be far more memory efficient, and not raise any garbage collection issues ...

Please explain or show exactly how you are specifying -Xmx. The default max-heap if you don't specify -Xmx is 1/4 the system RAM, and 1/4 of 48G is 12G, which after allowing for overheads and breakage is enough to allocate 5Gx2B but not 6Gx2B exactly as you are experiencing.

Your code is unnecessarily overcomplicated - such as the part scanning back each char[] to find \0 - you already know the length it contains. You don't need to allocate buffer at all, just write a line at a time to file until limit is reached and then switch to next file.

@meriton for benchmarking the performances actually. I wanted to see if reading everything at once and writing everything is faster than reading and writing line per line. I was wondering what was causing that error despite me allowing any (literally) max amount of memory to the heap.

@dave_thompson_085 java Main -Xmx32g from the windows CMD. Tried to avoid any IDE for making the understanding of the problem easier.
But even from IntelliJ after I set-up the heap limits (correctly) to any numer it still gives the same error with DIM = 6.
Thanks for the details! :))

@DuncG completely agree!
But the scope of the question is to find out why this crashes, not how to make it more efficient :)

@Rogue thanks for the answer!
Sorry but I didn't describe enough the error.
The program crashes when I try to inizialize the char[][].
I really appreciate your explaination anyways! :)

For general efficiency, if your code is waiting on other system processes then you're pretty much as optimal as you can be. If you want a "magic number" of bytes to target for reading/writing, I would target the block size of the filesystem you're writing to (which most hard drive firmware will be well-optimized to handle, and any file will be at least that size on disk anyhow). A BufferedWriter may very well already do this under the hood, hence the comment about just writing the lines as you read them.

I can run your program with DIM above 6. From your comments you use java Main -Xmx32g
You need to put VM args before the class name, otherwise -Xmx32g is an argument passed to Main.main(String ...args):
java -Xmx32g Main 

Another suggestion: if still not works for you, try a later JDK. I've used JDK22 with DIM set to 8, a 9GB file and java -Xmx20g Main - all runs OK.
There are easier ways to split a large file without such a big memory footprint, but based on your comment, this isn't part of your question - I hope this helps.

By the way - the split doesn't work

Hey! That did definitely fix my issue.
Fun fact: the code up here takes around 530 seconds for copying a file of 50GB.
While a simple read one line and write it takes around 360 seconds!
Thanks for sharing! :)
